# dotnet restore fail "Unable to resolve 'PCLLibrary' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0'."

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have PCL project('PCLLibrary') used in .NET CORE 1.0 project
all works fine from Visual Studion, 
bu fails when I try to do dotnet restore from command line.
I need it to build it on teamcity.

Errors in D:\WebExternal\WebExternal\src\Web\project.json
    Unable to resolve 'PCLLibrary' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0'.

I was trying to google it but didn't found any helpfull results.
Please, help me.

[Here you can get the project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-9jAXn2XowJNzlab1FLY2FWU2s/view?usp=sharing)

To test execute command "dotnet restore" from folder,
which contains project.json

Comment: Can you put your code somewhere? so that somebody can look into it.

Comment: I added project to body of question

Answer (score 3):

Move your PCLLibrary into src, it will work.

And some other improvements:

- In your webapplications3's project.json, the PCLLibrray should be
  moved to root dependencies section rather than
  frameworks'dependencies. it's not a framework dependency.
- And In you PCLLibrary, NETStandard.Library should be moved to
  frameworks dependencies.